# Shinyjs: Reference Error: ShinySenderQueue Is Not Defined: extendShinyJs()

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm having issues with using shinyjs's extendShinyjs() function.

**Background:** I'm creating a website through Shiny that features multiple pages, dynamically created. The pages are created based on a template I have defined in my ui.R file. A function: story_page(title, description, mediafile, name) takes in the parameters and generates a fluid page. The pages are all created when the app is run. I want to dynamically add photos to these pages after the button that brings the users to these pages is clicked.

The ideal flow I'm trying to create is:

- in ui.R I extend shinyjs and reference the file where my appending function is:

```
shinyjs::useShinyjs()
extendShinyjs(script="append_figures.js", functions=c("appendFigures"))
```

- in server.R I call this function on the actionButton click:

```
observeEvent(input$bosfutures2,{
    change_page("all_stories/boston-futures/rian")
    js$appendFigures(id="all-figures-container-rian", figure_vector=rian_figures)
  })
```

- Then in append_figures.js I have the following function defined:

```
shinyjs.appendFigures=function(params){
  console.log("point reached!");
  params=shinyjs.getParams(params);
  let id=$("#"+params.id);
  const fig_vector=params.figure_vector;
  
  for(let-i=0; i<fig_vector.length; i++){
    console.log("this is the figure vector index: ");
    console.log(i);
    let img=document.createElement("img");
    let source=concat("bosfutures/all_figures/", fig_vector[i], ".jpg"); //all are of type jpg
    console.log("this is the image file name: ");
    console.log(source);
    img.src=source;
    let div=document.getElementById(id);
    div.appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

The goal is to use the figure vector associated with the page to inform the program which of the pictures in the all_figures folder (see file organization below) should be selected and appended to the relevant container.

My file organization is as follows:

```
global.R
server.R
ui.R
www > 
   append_figures.js
   bosfutures >
       all_figures >
              1.jpg
              2.jpg
              ...
```

**Problem:**
I seem to be having issues with getting my shiny app to connect to the js file, as none of the console.log() messages appear. It doesn't seem like shiny is accessing my js file correctly. To see if js extends was working at all, I tried replicating the on page load example in the [shinyjs extends documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/extendShinyjs.html), which works directly in the ui.R file instead of trying to connect to an external .js file:

```
jsCode2<-"
shinyjs.init = function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) { alert('Key pressed: ' + e.which); });
}"

shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text=jsCode2, functions=c())
```

However, the keypress alert never shows up, meaning the issue is deeper than a file access problem...

In console.log() I get the following error messages:

```
VM1671:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: ShinySenderQueue is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:21
    at <anonymous>:10:9
    at b (jquery.min.js:2:866)
    at He (jquery.min.js:2:48373)
    at S.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:2:49724)
    at NM (singletons.ts:59:13)
    at lc (singletons.ts:10:3)
    at render.ts:179:45
    at v (render.ts:1:1357)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (render.ts:1:4174)
```

I'm not sure what it means...I've verified that shiny and shinyjs are successfully downloaded. Do you have any ideas what may be causing this issue? Thank you so much for your help!